# Is Wikipedia page on Kalman Filter's wrong?

Tags: kalman-filter

I was reading the wikipedia page on Kalman filter

[Snippet from wikipedia](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PYvSn.jpg)

There, when estimating the co-variance matrix, the Q matrix is used. When calculating Kalman gain, R matrix is used.

In most literature I found on Kalman filters, it is the other way around.

Here is a snippet from the Probabilistic Robotics written by Dr. Sebastian Thrun from Stanford.

[Kalman Filter snippet from Thrun's book](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gBEvI.jpg)

I guess it would be fair to assume that the wikipedia article is incorrect.

Just hoping someone could double check it to make sure I'm right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thrune is using $Q$ to denote the sensor noise covariance and $R$ to denote the process noise covariance. This is stated on [page 35](https://docs.ufpr.br/~danielsantos/ProbabilisticRobotics.pdf). Wikipedia uses the reverse of those definitions, defined in [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter#Underlying_dynamical_system_model) section. Neither is wrong. I would argue that Wikipedia's notation is actually more common; I have read quite a bit of literature on this subject.